# Nested LINQ Query at this case? How to create a nested groupby?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, nested

I need a help with nested LINQ here.

My scenario is

I have an List with

HotelId int
List

Inside rooms i have a roomid

I have a duplicated entries of hotels and duplicated entries of roomsid

Something like this

HoteId 2500

- RoomID 23
- RoomID 26

HotelId 3500

- RoomID 50
- RoomID 65

HotelId 2500

- RoomID 23

HotelId 3900

- RoomID 48

HotelId 3500

- RoomID 32

I want a group first by Hotel this is easy of course

```
listaHoteisEncontrados.GroupBy( x => x.HotelId );
```

But i need something in

```
Dictionary<int,List<rooms>>
```

where int is my IdHotel and rooms is a list of rooms i tried some samples here

```
Dictionary<int, List<Dados.HotelSearchResponse.Room>> otroDic =
        listaHoteisEncontrados
            .GroupBy( x => x.HotelId )
            .ToDictionary(
                g => g.Key,
                g => g
                    .GroupBy( e => e.Room
                        .GroupBy( f => f.RoomType ).ToDictionary
                        ( g2 => g2.Key, g2 => g2.Select( p => p.RoomType ).ToList() )
                        )
                );
```

without sucess.. can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried something similar to this approach  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2007/12/22/playing-with-linq-grouping-groupbymany.aspx?

Comment: well.. this worked, it isnt a good solution.. because i need read all the object again to make a dictionary with unique hotels and rooms.

Comment: are you wanting a dictonary that is Dictonary<HotelID, Dictonary<RoomType, List<Room>>?

Comment: No.. i want a Dictionary<HotelId, List<Rooms>>

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible solution. I only didn't manage to remove the duplicate rooms from the list.. :D

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, List<Room>>();
foreach (var hotel in listaHoteisEncontrados)
{
    if (!dic.ContainsKey(hotel.Id))
    {
        dic.Add(hotel.Id, hotel.Rooms);
    }
    else
    {
        dic[hotel.Id].AddRange(hotel.Rooms);
        //remove duplicate rooms here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi abbas, acctualy for a while i did with this solution but im sure there are a way to do in linq. For but thanks. I hope someone have a better solution in linq